# Optionally using capybara-webkit with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, capybara

I prefer to use capybara-webkit as the driver used with capybara, but don't expect other developers on my team to jump through the hoop of having QT installed in order to do the same. I'd like to remove capybara-webkit from the gemfile and only use it as the test driver when it can be required. I tried to do this with the following code in my spec_helper.rb file:

```
begin
  require 'capybara-webkit'
  driver = :webkit
  puts "capybara-webkit has been detected."
rescue LoadError
  driver = :selenium
  puts "capybara-webkit unavailable. Falling back to Selenium"
  puts "For faster, headless integration tests, install capybara-webkit"
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = driver
```

The problem is that even with capybara-webkit installed, the require fails. I can only assume this is because it's not in my application's bundle. How can I get around this? Is there a way to get around this that doesn't require capybara-webkit to be added to the Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than performing a require check, how about checking for another component that should be there instead? Something outside the scope of Ruby. You'd need to do this because of the gem being unavailable in the bundle.

Comment: Nice idea. I could see if I could detect QT, but when it comes down to it, the user still has to have the capybara-webkit gem. Hmmm. Wonder if there's a way I could add that condition to my gemfile. If QT is present, them install capybara-webkit.

Comment: I've basically given up on this. I thought I could use Gem.Available in my gemfile, but that's also limited to your bundle. I'll just try to require everyone to install QT!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd just want to add a custom group to the Gemfile and put capybara-webkit there. Other developers can then install the bundle, but exclude that group.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about going that way, but I don't think it will work for us. I like to keep .bundle/config checked into source control because it's set so that all gems are vendored for this project. If I run `bundle install` with different params, I believe bundler updates that file. The next time `bundle install` is run, the params are pulled from the config file. With them excluding that group and me including it, wouldn't we just constantly be updating that file?

Comment: Yes, you would be constantly updating that file. Checking .bundle/config into source control is not recommended, although you may be able to get away with it by specifying your personal settings in ~/.bundler/config. This obviously promotes these settings to global rather than per-project, so this may not be a fit for you.

Answer (score -1):

I like to use both as well, in general, webkit is faster, but sometimes I like to see the browser doing stuff(like when I have no idea what is happening, or to show to a client) my resolution is to have both installed via the gemfile, and set this in your spec_helper.rb

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit unless ENV['SHOWJS']
```

This leaves my default to the headless driver, and when I want to see it in selenium I can run this command:

```
SHOWJS=1 rspec spec/features/user/new_spec.rb
```

If you use guard or something, you might have to export the environment variable because I don't think you can just pass it in.